# OpenCV difference between roslaunch and rosrun

Tags: ros, roslaunch, ros-kinetic, rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
OS: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS Xenial
ROS: Kinetic.
OPenCV: 3.2.0-dev
Python 2.7.12
ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/kinetic/share/ros
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/odroid/ros_ws/src:/opt/ros/kinetic/share
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES=/home/odroid/ros_ws/devel/share/common-lisp
ROS_DISTRO=kinetic
ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/kinetic/etc/ros
```

If I run a python script through a launch file, OpenCV cannot open a camera,  but running it manually openCV works fine.

Here’s the bare bones Code Snippet where it works/fails.

```
 print cv2.__version__
   camera=cv2.VideoCapture("/dev/video8")
   print camera
   if not camera.isOpened():
       camera=None
       print "No camera"
   return camera
```

Here’s the line from the launch file:

```
<node name="whisker_sensor" pkg="ros_whisker_sensor" type="whisker_sensor.py" respawn="false" output="screen"/>
```

Here’s the output of the screen dump from that launch:

```
….
process[whisker_sensor-10]: started with pid [32257]
3.2.0-dev
<VideoCapture 0xb6d487b0>
No camera
….
```

Notice it sets up a camera Object, but it fails to open.

However if I kill the specific node and then re-run it manually from a rosrun command: like this:

```
odroid@fish01:~$ rosnode kill /whisker_sensor ; rosrun ros_whisker_sensor whisker_sensor.py
killing /whisker_sensor
killed
3.2.0-dev
<VideoCapture 0xb6d017b0>
136 0.723058982284
136 0.723058982284
134 0.731470868094
```

It passes the isOpened() check and starts dumping the data I’m looking for from a processed image.

Does anyone have any thoughts as to why `camera.isOpened()` fails under a roslaunch but works under a rosrun?  Is there any way I can get more informative information out of the camera function?  I have a feeling its a path or library issue, but I can't figure out what's different between the launch file and run approaches.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280871/opencv-difference-between-roslaunch-and-rosrun/) by [graeme](https://answers.ros.org/users/33427/graeme/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2018-01-25

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rdelgadov](https://answers.ros.org/users/33433/rdelgadov/) on 2018-01-26**:
If is a usb camera you will try to use [usb_cam](https://github.com/ros-drivers/usb_cam) package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I ended up installing usb_cam as suggested,(I'm going to use it eventually) but in the process discovered the solution from a problem someone else had with usb_cam:

https://answers.ros.org/question/219886/libuvc-launch-get-permission-denied-opening-usb-error/

The camera code needs to have un-restricted access to the /dev/video## ports.

by doing this:

```
 sudo chmod a+rwx /dev/video*
```

Prior to starting the ros stack, my ros code has access to the camera.  I added this chmod to my start up script and I'm all set.

---

Originally posted by [graeme](https://answers.ros.org/users/33427/graeme/) with karma: 46 on 2018-01-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0